# Normalize Name-Surname strings: PHP+REGEX (Spanish chars- UTF8)

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

I'm having strings with name and surname which I need to normalize with a functiont and make them like:

Name Surname (I can recive strings like NAME SURNAME, Name SURNAME, etc...)

I've found this [snipet](https://www.php.net/ucfirst#81258):

```
echo nameize("HÉCTOR MAÑAÇ"); 



function nameize($str,$a_char = array("'","-"," ")){    
    //$str contains the complete raw name string
    //$a_char is an array containing the characters we use as separators for capitalization. If you don't pass anything, there are three in there as default.
    $string = strtolower($str);
    foreach ($a_char as $temp){
        $pos = strpos($string,$temp);
        if ($pos){
            //we are in the loop because we found one of the special characters in the array, so lets split it up into chunks and capitalize each one.
            $mend = '';
            $a_split = explode($temp,$string);
            foreach ($a_split as $temp2){
                //capitalize each portion of the string which was separated at a special character
                $mend .= ucfirst($temp2).$temp;
                }
            $string = substr($mend,0,-1);
            }    
        }
    return ucfirst($string);
    }
```

Which works pretty well, but, as you can see testing this exact example, doesn't parse spanish chars (utf8) I've tested mb_regex_encoding("UTF-8"); mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");, headers UTF8, etc. But can't make it work fine with "special" spanish chars.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't see, where you use the [Multibyte String Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php).

Maybe this would be convenient for your needs:

```
echo mb_convert_case("HÉCTOR MAÑAÇ", MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
```

*[output](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/aqz-42g)*:

```
Héctor Mañaç
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function works fine for the given example also. Please check your file encoding type. It must be UTF-8. You can check it in Notepadd++.

Comment: Yup, my file is also encoded with UTF8, and result is like: HÉctor MaÑaÇ

Comment: I tested your code with same and it is working correctly. Getting this "Héctor Mañaç".

Comment: Please try it again by putting encoding as "ANSI"

Comment: file reconverted to ANSI, UTF8 and UTF8 whitout BUM, same results, may be the issue related with server config?